Fortran "new line"?
So I have this Fortran code:
xo  = xo  +  delta
      no  = no  +  nx
      mo  = mo  +  mx
      Ro  = Ro  +  Rx
      R1o = R1o +  R1x
      Po  = Po  +  Px
      Mso = Mso +  Msx
      Mbo = Mbo +  Mbx
        i =  i  +  1

      if(i.eq.50000*int(i/50000)) then
        print*,'i= ',i,'; Log10(Radio)= ',Log10(Radio),'; P= ',Po,
     1           '; Masa= ',Mso
        print*, '-g_tt =  ', no, ';   g_rr =  ', mo
        print*, 'g_tt*g_rr=  ', no*mo       !*.299151515d0
        print*, 'no_central =  ', 1.d0/no
        print*, 'Escalar de curvatura:  R =  ', Ro
        print*, 'denominador =  ', 2.d0*f1o+xo*R1o*f2o,'  R1 =  ', R1o
        print*, 'R1²f2²/f1 =  ', R1o**2.d0*f2o**2.d0/f1o
        print*, 'f/f2 =  ', fo/f2o,'    f1R/f2 =   ', f1o*Ro/f2o
        print*, 'f3R²/f2 =  ', f3o*Ro**2.d0/f2o
        print*, 'Error de R =  ',error_R
        print*, 'Radio =  ', xo
        print*, '----------------------------------------------------'
      endif

      Enddo
       no_central=1.d0/no
      END

and I'm trying to write it out in Python.
First of all, I'm not sure what the index "i" is doing because it's never mentioned before. I assumed it was for some kind of "for" loop. is it for the "if" statement? I kind of understand that the first time it's mentioned in the code it means that it'll increment by "1". But aside from that, I have no idea what it does in this part of the code (the only part it's mentioned in the entire program).
Second: in the line print*,'i= ',i,'; Log10(Radio)= ',Log10(Radio),'; P= ',Po,'; Masa= ',Mso I don't understand if the semicolon indicates some kind of "new line" when it's printed. Does anyone know what it does?
I tried looking for a solution online, but couldn't find one. I understand that it might not be something difficult (for someone who uses Fortran); but I'm unfamiliar with Fortran.

i is just counting iterations, so the data dump is only done every 50,000 cycles.  The semi-colon is just a literal semi-colon.  It has no other meaning.

For the i variable, I think the code you shared is incomplete. The reason I say that is I see Enddo but I don't the the DO which begins the loop, which is probably where i is declared.

The existance of enddo indicates that this is part of a while loop, and that you therefor haven't included all of the code.

Normally when someone uses a semicolon in writing something out it's to provide a break between different items. If your output is "i=1; j=2; k=3" I don't think we need to try to guess what's intended, whether a "new line" or anything else.


First of all, I'm not sure what the index "i" is doing because it's never mentioned before.

i here is just a integer variable that is used as an index and is incremented on every iteration of a DO loop. It is confusing in your snippet because it is incomplete: I know that because there is a EndDo at the end, which indicates the existence of a opening DO-loop.
Fortran has only one loop constructor, which is the DO, but it can have different forms. Considering that this program is incrementing the index variable explicitly with i =  i  +  1, I would infer it is using the while form, that should look like this:
while (logical expr) do
   statements
enddo

Have a second look in your complete code, you should be able to find it.

Second: in the line (...) I don't understand if the semicolon indicates some kind of "new line"

No, the semicolon there is just a literal semicolon, as part of a text that will be printed into the screen.
In Fortran, the print statement is a concise way to output text. It has some syntax options, but the one used in your snippet looks like this:
 print *, text, text, text

Where those text are actually either a character literal (basically a string, which is enclosed by quotes, like '; Log10(Radio)= ' or any other expression that results a printable value (like that Log10(Radio), without quotes). Each of those terms is separated by a comma.
So, when you see something like:
print *, 'i= ', i, '; Log10(Radio)= ', Log10(Radio), '; P= ', Po, '; Masa= ',Mso

It is just printing each of those terms in the output: the text i= , followed by the value of the variable i, then the text '; Log10(Radio)= ', the value of the expression Log10(Radio), and so on.
The quoted ones are printed as is, including the semicolon, that is inside the quotes.
